# Global and local argument names in renderer(_:didAdd:for:) method

Tags: objective-c, swift, scenekit, arkit

We always use local parameter names (***node*** and ***anchor***) in SceneKit methods like:

```
optional func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor)
```

In which case the global argument names ***didAdd*** and ***for*** can be used?

Comment: didAdd and for are not parameters. They are labels to make the function name more expressive.

Comment: Sorry @EmilioPelaez, but why they aren't `didAddNode` and `forAnchor` then? It's more expressive, isn't it?

Comment: Because you already have the “node” and “anchor” as the parameter names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern follows the [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/):

> More words may be needed to clarify intent or disambiguate meaning, but those that are redundant with information the reader already possesses should be omitted. In particular, omit words that merely *repeat* type information.

While the Objective-C API is:

```
- (void)renderer:(id<SCNSceneRenderer>)renderer 
      didAddNode:(SCNNode *)node 
       forAnchor:(ARAnchor *)anchor;
```

It is translated into Swift as:

```
optional func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, 
                didAdd node: SCNNode, 
                   for anchor: ARAnchor)
```

Presumably the caller knows the types of the arguments so the type information was omitted.

This is also the way Objective-C methods are automatically translated into Swift; see [Name Translation from C to Swift](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/CToSwiftNameTranslation.md) and [Omit-needless-words](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/CToSwiftNameTranslation-OmitNeedlessWords.md).